# TypeORM Can't create entity table with dot in name

Tags: node.js, sql-server, nestjs, typeorm

Using TestORM to connect to an already created table.  The caveat is that it, along with most tables in my firm, has a dot in the name: dbo.Application

My entity file:

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm'

@Entity({name: 'Application'}) // fixed
export class Application {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  ApplicationID: number;

  @Column()
  ApplicationName: string;

  @Column()
  LastUpdate: number;
}
```

EDIT
Okay, I see the issue.  Without {name: 'Application'} it tries to create the table 'application', not 'Application'

However, I have a new error and I cannot figure it out. It looks like TestORM is trying to drop the ApplicationName column, which is type varchar(100).  Do it and string not jive?

For the record, DB columns are:

ApplicationID(PK, int, not null)

ApplicationName(varchar(100),null)

LastUpdate(datetime,null)

EDIT again:
Setting synchronize: false in the connection prevents it from dropping the column. Still curious why it tried it before but this is livable.

Comment: dbo.Application is not the name of the table. That is the schema and the table name. Otherwise you would to write queries like select * from dbo.[dbo.Application] And if you are seriously using dbo. in your object names then something went horribly wrong as that is just awful.

Comment: Curious then why it was trying to create a table every time I started it.  The error is different now.  Will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create objects with unusual characters in the name, enclose the name in square brackets, like this: `[My-Table!]`. However in your case you probably don't want to do it as `dbo` is not a part of table name, but a name of a schema, as @sean-lange correctly pointed out.

Comment: Cheers. Got that.  I do have another error though [question updated], which I'm guessing b/c the types are different